# Difference between multivariate Gaussian distribution and multivariate Gaussian mixture model

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

I would like to know the difference between a multivariate Gaussian distribution and multivariate Gaussian mixture model. Can someone provide an intuitive and/or detailed explanation?

Thanks.

Comment: See, for example, [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/195911/15941) for a multivariate Gaussian mixture model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A (non-degenerate) multivariate Gaussian density function has a specific form 
$$f(\mathbf x) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}\sqrt{\det(\Sigma)}}
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathbf x - \mathbf m\right)\Sigma^{-1}
(\mathbf x - \mathbf m)^T \right).\tag{1}$$

A  multivariate Gaussian *mixture* model is a weighted sum of densities such as $(1)$:

$$f(\mathbf x) = \sum_{i=1}^N p_i\cdot\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}\sqrt{\det(\Sigma_i)}}
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathbf x - \mathbf m_i\right)\Sigma^{-1}_i
(\mathbf x - \mathbf m_i)^T \right)$$
where the $p_i$ are positive numbers such that $\sum_{i=1}^N p_i = 1$.
Effectively, we have $N$ mutually exclusive
events $A_i$ such that the *conditional*
density *given* that $A_i$ occurred is
$$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}\sqrt{\det(\Sigma_i)}}
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathbf x - \mathbf m_i\right)\Sigma^{-1}_i
(\mathbf x - \mathbf m_i)^T \right)$$
and $(2)$ is just the law-of-total-probability expression for the
*unconditional* density.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you can have a look at my other question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171307/how-to-train-a-gaussian-mixture-hidden-markov-model

Comment: This can be done completely generally by using distribution or characteristic functions instead of densities. That allows for one or more of the Gaussians being mixed to be degenerate.